# add svg loader to html5 canvs

Tags: html, svg, canvas

I have this html5 canvas file (adobe animate) and i want to use an svg animated loader for it (the svg loader code is at the end of the html file) but i am not really sure how to do it, especially that the body onload is already taken, can somebody show me how to do it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    NOTES:
    1. All tokens are represented by '$' sign in the template.
    2. You can write your code only wherever mentioned.
    3. All occurrences of existing tokens will be replaced by their appropriate values.
    4. Blank lines will be removed automatically.
    5. Remove unnecessary comments before creating your template.
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="authoring-tool" content="Adobe_Animate_CC">
<title>1</title>
<!-- write your code here -->
<style>
  #animation_container {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;right:0;
    top:0;bottom:0;
  }
</style>
<script src="createjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, fnStartAnimation;
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
    dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
    var comp=AdobeAn.getComposition("84461339880503479AB31885C2CE7CD2");
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", function(evt){handleComplete(evt,comp)});
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}
function handleComplete(evt,comp) {
    //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var ss=comp.getSpriteSheet();
    var queue = evt.target;
    var ssMetadata = lib.ssMetadata;
    for(i=0; i<ssMetadata.length; i++) {
        ss[ssMetadata[i].name] = new createjs.SpriteSheet( {"images": [queue.getResult(ssMetadata[i].name)], "frames": ssMetadata[i].frames} )
    }
    exportRoot = new lib._1();
    stage = new lib.Stage(canvas);
    stage.enableMouseOver();    
    //Registers the "tick" event listener.
    fnStartAnimation = function() {
        stage.addChild(exportRoot);
        createjs.Ticker.framerate = lib.properties.fps;
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }       
    //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
    AdobeAn.makeResponsive(true,'both',true,1,[canvas,anim_container,dom_overlay_container]);   
    AdobeAn.compositionLoaded(lib.properties.id);
    fnStartAnimation();
}
function playSound(id, loop) {
    return createjs.Sound.play(id, {'interrupt':createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_EARLY, 'loop': loop});}
</script>
<!-- write your code here -->
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
    <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00); width:1366px; height:768px">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1366" height="768" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);"></canvas>
        <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:1366px; height:768px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org"
    id="camera-loader"
   width="85.708488"
   height="100">
  <defs
     id="defs12" />
  <path
     id="camera-body"
     d="M 51.5625 0 C 50.667739 -0.00962983 49.756943 0.05800477 48.84375 0.1875 C 41.018415 1.2971691 35.117198 7.3376842 33.8125 14.71875 C 30.504071 7.9918491 23.138091 3.8277945 15.3125 4.9375 C 5.573576 6.3185261 -1.1937811 15.321773 0.1875 25.0625 C 1.030765 31.00916 4.7245026 35.850708 9.6875 38.40625 L 10.59375 44.84375 L 41.21875 40.5 C 42.618434 40.301472 43.966737 41.101389 44.15625 42.4375 C 44.34576 43.773612 43.274684 44.957723 41.875 45.15625 L 11.25 49.5 L 12.40625 57.6875 C 12.593105 59.005185 13.837018 59.937079 15.15625 59.75 L 64.25 52.78125 C 65.567815 52.594377 66.499355 51.348937 66.3125 50.03125 L 63.5625 30.78125 C 67.618077 26.946961 69.843395 21.259142 69 15.3125 C 67.748216 6.4849658 60.211858 0.09304631 51.5625 0 z M 51.28125 3.75 C 58.168631 3.6506107 64.22589 8.6859174 65.21875 15.6875 C 66.295328 23.279482 61.029156 30.329715 53.4375 31.40625 C 45.84552 32.482829 38.795329 27.18573 37.71875 19.59375 C 36.641441 11.998855 41.938942 4.9828747 49.53125 3.90625 C 50.124347 3.8221462 50.697574 3.7584222 51.28125 3.75 z M 17.5625 8.53125 C 24.449868 8.4318561 30.507144 13.46718 31.5 20.46875 C 32.576577 28.060719 27.310389 35.110969 19.71875 36.1875 C 12.126783 37.264077 5.0765804 31.966969 4 24.375 C 2.9226914 16.780121 8.2202041 9.7641225 15.8125 8.6875 C 16.405598 8.603395 16.978824 8.5396714 17.5625 8.53125 z M 79.71875 27.46875 L 66.9375 33.65625 L 68.53125 44.8125 L 82.53125 47.21875 L 79.71875 27.46875 z M 41.71875 41.0625 C 41.582761 41.058251 41.422178 41.073761 41.28125 41.09375 L 8.15625 45.78125 L 7.90625 44.09375 L 2.78125 43.9375 L 4 52.53125 L 8.875 50.9375 L 8.625 49.25 L 41.78125 44.5625 C 42.908673 44.40259 43.699053 43.493996 43.5625 42.53125 C 43.443014 41.688847 42.670671 41.092246 41.71875 41.0625 z M 51.53125 57.21875 L 28.625 60.4375 C 28.625117 63.279515 28.625057 61.501735 28.625 64.34375 L 30.90625 64.34375 L 32.40625 64.34375 L 17.21875 97.46875 C 16.804629 98.371268 17.19123 99.429629 18.09375 99.84375 C 18.996268 100.25787 20.054629 99.87127 20.46875 98.96875 L 36.34375 64.34375 L 38.28125 64.34375 L 38.28125 98.21875 C 38.28125 99.211743 39.069507 100 40.0625 100 C 41.055493 100 41.875 99.211743 41.875 98.21875 L 41.875 64.34375 L 43.6875 64.34375 L 59.71875 98.96875 C 60.136118 99.869771 61.192729 100.26112 62.09375 99.84375 C 62.994771 99.426382 63.386118 98.338521 62.96875 97.4375 L 47.65625 64.34375 L 49.09375 64.34375 L 51.53125 64.34375 L 51.53125 57.21875 z " />
  <path
     id="reel-1"
     d="m 17.763265,10.60917 c -1.849868,0 -3.349902,1.500036 -3.349902,3.349902 0,1.849868 1.500034,3.34863 3.349902,3.34863 1.849865,0 3.348629,-1.498762 3.348629,-3.34863 0,-1.849866 -1.498764,-3.349902 -3.348629,-3.349902 z m -8.0539896,5.851215 c -1.849868,0 -3.3499023,1.500032 -3.3499023,3.349898 0,1.849866 1.5000343,3.349897 3.3499023,3.349897 1.8498656,0 3.3498996,-1.500031 3.3498996,-3.349897 0,-1.849866 -1.500034,-3.349898 -3.3498996,-3.349898 z m 16.1016246,0 c -1.849868,0 -3.3499,1.500032 -3.3499,3.349898 0,1.849866 1.500032,3.349897 3.3499,3.349897 1.849865,0 3.348629,-1.500031 3.348629,-3.349897 0,-1.849866 -1.498764,-3.349898 -3.348629,-3.349898 z m -13.023579,9.460259 c -1.849867,0 -3.3498994,1.500032 -3.3498994,3.349902 0,1.849865 1.5000324,3.348629 3.3498994,3.348629 1.849867,0 3.3499,-1.498764 3.3499,-3.348629 0,-1.84987 -1.500033,-3.349902 -3.3499,-3.349902 z m 9.950613,0 c -1.849866,0 -3.348629,1.500032 -3.348629,3.349902 0,1.849865 1.498763,3.348629 3.348629,3.348629 1.849865,0 3.349901,-1.498764 3.349901,-3.348629 0,-1.84987 -1.500036,-3.349902 -3.349901,-3.349902 z">
    <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       attributeType="XML"
       type="rotate"
       dur="2s"
       begin="0"
       from="0 17.66 22.74"
       to="360 17.66 22.74"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  <path
     id="reel-2"
     d="m 51.483904,5.8171007 c -1.849872,0 -3.349908,1.5000388 -3.349908,3.3499074 0,1.8498709 1.500036,3.3486359 3.349908,3.3486359 1.849868,0 3.348635,-1.498765 3.348635,-3.3486359 0,-1.8498686 -1.498767,-3.3499074 -3.348635,-3.3499074 z M 43.4299,11.668326 c -1.849872,0 -3.349908,1.500034 -3.349908,3.349904 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.349903 3.349908,3.349903 1.849869,0 3.349906,-1.500034 3.349906,-3.349903 0,-1.84987 -1.500037,-3.349904 -3.349906,-3.349904 z m 16.101654,0 c -1.849871,0 -3.349907,1.500034 -3.349907,3.349904 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.349903 3.349907,3.349903 1.849867,0 3.348635,-1.500034 3.348635,-3.349903 0,-1.84987 -1.498768,-3.349904 -3.348635,-3.349904 z m -13.023602,9.460276 c -1.849871,0 -3.349907,1.500034 -3.349907,3.349908 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.348635 3.349907,3.348635 1.849869,0 3.349905,-1.498766 3.349905,-3.348635 0,-1.849874 -1.500036,-3.349908 -3.349905,-3.349908 z m 9.950632,0 c -1.849872,0 -3.348637,1.500034 -3.348637,3.349908 0,1.849869 1.498765,3.348635 3.348637,3.348635 1.849867,0 3.349905,-1.498766 3.349905,-3.348635 0,-1.849874 -1.500038,-3.349908 -3.349905,-3.349908 z">
    <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       attributeType="XML"
       type="rotate"
       dur="3.6s"
       begin="0"
       from="0 51.4 17.7"
       to="360 51.4 17.7"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>

<span>Loading&hellip;</span>
```

Comment: thanks, (9 more to go... ) (so i can post the thanks )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked, i just replaced the gif preloaded with an svg, thanks for "fatalcoder524" for helping

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    NOTES:
    1. All tokens are represented by '$' sign in the template.
    2. You can write your code only wherever mentioned.
    3. All occurrences of existing tokens will be replaced by their appropriate values.
    4. Blank lines will be removed automatically.
    5. Remove unnecessary comments before creating your template.
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="authoring-tool" content="Adobe_Animate_CC">
<title>1</title>
<!-- write your code here -->
<style>
  #animation_container, #_preload_div_ {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;right:0;
    top:0;bottom:0;
  }
  #camera-loader {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;right:0;
    top:0;bottom:0;
  }

</style>
<script src="createjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, fnStartAnimation;
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
    dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
    var comp=AdobeAn.getComposition("84461339880503479AB31885C2CE7CD2");
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", function(evt){handleComplete(evt,comp)});
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}
function handleComplete(evt,comp) {
    //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var ss=comp.getSpriteSheet();
    var queue = evt.target;
    var ssMetadata = lib.ssMetadata;
    for(i=0; i<ssMetadata.length; i++) {
        ss[ssMetadata[i].name] = new createjs.SpriteSheet( {"images": [queue.getResult(ssMetadata[i].name)], "frames": ssMetadata[i].frames} )
    }
    var preloaderDiv = document.getElementById("_preload_div_");
    preloaderDiv.style.display = 'none';
    canvas.style.display = 'block';
    exportRoot = new lib._1();
    stage = new lib.Stage(canvas);
    stage.enableMouseOver();    
    //Registers the "tick" event listener.
    fnStartAnimation = function() {
        stage.addChild(exportRoot);
        createjs.Ticker.framerate = lib.properties.fps;
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }       
    //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
    AdobeAn.makeResponsive(true,'both',true,1,[canvas,preloaderDiv,anim_container,dom_overlay_container]);  
    AdobeAn.compositionLoaded(lib.properties.id);
    fnStartAnimation();
}
function playSound(id, loop) {
    return createjs.Sound.play(id, {'interrupt':createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_EARLY, 'loop': loop});}
</script>
<!-- write your code here -->
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
    <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00); width:1366px; height:768px">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1366" height="768" style="position: absolute; display: none; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);"></canvas>
        <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:1366px; height:768px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='_preload_div_' ><svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org"
         id="camera-loader"
        width="85.708488"
        height="100">
       <defs
          id="defs12" />
       <path
          id="camera-body"
          d="M 51.5625 0 C 50.667739 -0.00962983 49.756943 0.05800477 48.84375 0.1875 C 41.018415 1.2971691 35.117198 7.3376842 33.8125 14.71875 C 30.504071 7.9918491 23.138091 3.8277945 15.3125 4.9375 C 5.573576 6.3185261 -1.1937811 15.321773 0.1875 25.0625 C 1.030765 31.00916 4.7245026 35.850708 9.6875 38.40625 L 10.59375 44.84375 L 41.21875 40.5 C 42.618434 40.301472 43.966737 41.101389 44.15625 42.4375 C 44.34576 43.773612 43.274684 44.957723 41.875 45.15625 L 11.25 49.5 L 12.40625 57.6875 C 12.593105 59.005185 13.837018 59.937079 15.15625 59.75 L 64.25 52.78125 C 65.567815 52.594377 66.499355 51.348937 66.3125 50.03125 L 63.5625 30.78125 C 67.618077 26.946961 69.843395 21.259142 69 15.3125 C 67.748216 6.4849658 60.211858 0.09304631 51.5625 0 z M 51.28125 3.75 C 58.168631 3.6506107 64.22589 8.6859174 65.21875 15.6875 C 66.295328 23.279482 61.029156 30.329715 53.4375 31.40625 C 45.84552 32.482829 38.795329 27.18573 37.71875 19.59375 C 36.641441 11.998855 41.938942 4.9828747 49.53125 3.90625 C 50.124347 3.8221462 50.697574 3.7584222 51.28125 3.75 z M 17.5625 8.53125 C 24.449868 8.4318561 30.507144 13.46718 31.5 20.46875 C 32.576577 28.060719 27.310389 35.110969 19.71875 36.1875 C 12.126783 37.264077 5.0765804 31.966969 4 24.375 C 2.9226914 16.780121 8.2202041 9.7641225 15.8125 8.6875 C 16.405598 8.603395 16.978824 8.5396714 17.5625 8.53125 z M 79.71875 27.46875 L 66.9375 33.65625 L 68.53125 44.8125 L 82.53125 47.21875 L 79.71875 27.46875 z M 41.71875 41.0625 C 41.582761 41.058251 41.422178 41.073761 41.28125 41.09375 L 8.15625 45.78125 L 7.90625 44.09375 L 2.78125 43.9375 L 4 52.53125 L 8.875 50.9375 L 8.625 49.25 L 41.78125 44.5625 C 42.908673 44.40259 43.699053 43.493996 43.5625 42.53125 C 43.443014 41.688847 42.670671 41.092246 41.71875 41.0625 z M 51.53125 57.21875 L 28.625 60.4375 C 28.625117 63.279515 28.625057 61.501735 28.625 64.34375 L 30.90625 64.34375 L 32.40625 64.34375 L 17.21875 97.46875 C 16.804629 98.371268 17.19123 99.429629 18.09375 99.84375 C 18.996268 100.25787 20.054629 99.87127 20.46875 98.96875 L 36.34375 64.34375 L 38.28125 64.34375 L 38.28125 98.21875 C 38.28125 99.211743 39.069507 100 40.0625 100 C 41.055493 100 41.875 99.211743 41.875 98.21875 L 41.875 64.34375 L 43.6875 64.34375 L 59.71875 98.96875 C 60.136118 99.869771 61.192729 100.26112 62.09375 99.84375 C 62.994771 99.426382 63.386118 98.338521 62.96875 97.4375 L 47.65625 64.34375 L 49.09375 64.34375 L 51.53125 64.34375 L 51.53125 57.21875 z " />
       <path
          id="reel-1"
          d="m 17.763265,10.60917 c -1.849868,0 -3.349902,1.500036 -3.349902,3.349902 0,1.849868 1.500034,3.34863 3.349902,3.34863 1.849865,0 3.348629,-1.498762 3.348629,-3.34863 0,-1.849866 -1.498764,-3.349902 -3.348629,-3.349902 z m -8.0539896,5.851215 c -1.849868,0 -3.3499023,1.500032 -3.3499023,3.349898 0,1.849866 1.5000343,3.349897 3.3499023,3.349897 1.8498656,0 3.3498996,-1.500031 3.3498996,-3.349897 0,-1.849866 -1.500034,-3.349898 -3.3498996,-3.349898 z m 16.1016246,0 c -1.849868,0 -3.3499,1.500032 -3.3499,3.349898 0,1.849866 1.500032,3.349897 3.3499,3.349897 1.849865,0 3.348629,-1.500031 3.348629,-3.349897 0,-1.849866 -1.498764,-3.349898 -3.348629,-3.349898 z m -13.023579,9.460259 c -1.849867,0 -3.3498994,1.500032 -3.3498994,3.349902 0,1.849865 1.5000324,3.348629 3.3498994,3.348629 1.849867,0 3.3499,-1.498764 3.3499,-3.348629 0,-1.84987 -1.500033,-3.349902 -3.3499,-3.349902 z m 9.950613,0 c -1.849866,0 -3.348629,1.500032 -3.348629,3.349902 0,1.849865 1.498763,3.348629 3.348629,3.348629 1.849865,0 3.349901,-1.498764 3.349901,-3.348629 0,-1.84987 -1.500036,-3.349902 -3.349901,-3.349902 z">
         <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            attributeType="XML"
            type="rotate"
            dur="2s"
            begin="0"
            from="0 17.66 22.74"
            to="360 17.66 22.74"
            repeatCount="indefinite" />
       </path>
       <path
          id="reel-2"
          d="m 51.483904,5.8171007 c -1.849872,0 -3.349908,1.5000388 -3.349908,3.3499074 0,1.8498709 1.500036,3.3486359 3.349908,3.3486359 1.849868,0 3.348635,-1.498765 3.348635,-3.3486359 0,-1.8498686 -1.498767,-3.3499074 -3.348635,-3.3499074 z M 43.4299,11.668326 c -1.849872,0 -3.349908,1.500034 -3.349908,3.349904 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.349903 3.349908,3.349903 1.849869,0 3.349906,-1.500034 3.349906,-3.349903 0,-1.84987 -1.500037,-3.349904 -3.349906,-3.349904 z m 16.101654,0 c -1.849871,0 -3.349907,1.500034 -3.349907,3.349904 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.349903 3.349907,3.349903 1.849867,0 3.348635,-1.500034 3.348635,-3.349903 0,-1.84987 -1.498768,-3.349904 -3.348635,-3.349904 z m -13.023602,9.460276 c -1.849871,0 -3.349907,1.500034 -3.349907,3.349908 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.348635 3.349907,3.348635 1.849869,0 3.349905,-1.498766 3.349905,-3.348635 0,-1.849874 -1.500036,-3.349908 -3.349905,-3.349908 z m 9.950632,0 c -1.849872,0 -3.348637,1.500034 -3.348637,3.349908 0,1.849869 1.498765,3.348635 3.348637,3.348635 1.849867,0 3.349905,-1.498766 3.349905,-3.348635 0,-1.849874 -1.500038,-3.349908 -3.349905,-3.349908 z">
         <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            attributeType="XML"
            type="rotate"
            dur="3.6s"
            begin="0"
            from="0 51.4 17.7"
            to="360 51.4 17.7"
            repeatCount="indefinite" />
       </path>
     </svg>
     
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't post it as answer. Just update it in your question. After question, write as Update in bold and write it. And click thanks or upvote it if helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a preloader simple way would be:-

A div with Preloader code:-
(Class is important as it will be used in JS)

```
<div class="loader">
  <svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org"
    id="camera-loader"
   width="85.708488"
   height="100">
  <defs
     id="defs12" />
  <path
     id="camera-body"
     d="M 51.5625 0 C 50.667739 -0.00962983 49.756943 0.05800477 48.84375 0.1875 C 41.018415 1.2971691 35.117198 7.3376842 33.8125 14.71875 C 30.504071 7.9918491 23.138091 3.8277945 15.3125 4.9375 C 5.573576 6.3185261 -1.1937811 15.321773 0.1875 25.0625 C 1.030765 31.00916 4.7245026 35.850708 9.6875 38.40625 L 10.59375 44.84375 L 41.21875 40.5 C 42.618434 40.301472 43.966737 41.101389 44.15625 42.4375 C 44.34576 43.773612 43.274684 44.957723 41.875 45.15625 L 11.25 49.5 L 12.40625 57.6875 C 12.593105 59.005185 13.837018 59.937079 15.15625 59.75 L 64.25 52.78125 C 65.567815 52.594377 66.499355 51.348937 66.3125 50.03125 L 63.5625 30.78125 C 67.618077 26.946961 69.843395 21.259142 69 15.3125 C 67.748216 6.4849658 60.211858 0.09304631 51.5625 0 z M 51.28125 3.75 C 58.168631 3.6506107 64.22589 8.6859174 65.21875 15.6875 C 66.295328 23.279482 61.029156 30.329715 53.4375 31.40625 C 45.84552 32.482829 38.795329 27.18573 37.71875 19.59375 C 36.641441 11.998855 41.938942 4.9828747 49.53125 3.90625 C 50.124347 3.8221462 50.697574 3.7584222 51.28125 3.75 z M 17.5625 8.53125 C 24.449868 8.4318561 30.507144 13.46718 31.5 20.46875 C 32.576577 28.060719 27.310389 35.110969 19.71875 36.1875 C 12.126783 37.264077 5.0765804 31.966969 4 24.375 C 2.9226914 16.780121 8.2202041 9.7641225 15.8125 8.6875 C 16.405598 8.603395 16.978824 8.5396714 17.5625 8.53125 z M 79.71875 27.46875 L 66.9375 33.65625 L 68.53125 44.8125 L 82.53125 47.21875 L 79.71875 27.46875 z M 41.71875 41.0625 C 41.582761 41.058251 41.422178 41.073761 41.28125 41.09375 L 8.15625 45.78125 L 7.90625 44.09375 L 2.78125 43.9375 L 4 52.53125 L 8.875 50.9375 L 8.625 49.25 L 41.78125 44.5625 C 42.908673 44.40259 43.699053 43.493996 43.5625 42.53125 C 43.443014 41.688847 42.670671 41.092246 41.71875 41.0625 z M 51.53125 57.21875 L 28.625 60.4375 C 28.625117 63.279515 28.625057 61.501735 28.625 64.34375 L 30.90625 64.34375 L 32.40625 64.34375 L 17.21875 97.46875 C 16.804629 98.371268 17.19123 99.429629 18.09375 99.84375 C 18.996268 100.25787 20.054629 99.87127 20.46875 98.96875 L 36.34375 64.34375 L 38.28125 64.34375 L 38.28125 98.21875 C 38.28125 99.211743 39.069507 100 40.0625 100 C 41.055493 100 41.875 99.211743 41.875 98.21875 L 41.875 64.34375 L 43.6875 64.34375 L 59.71875 98.96875 C 60.136118 99.869771 61.192729 100.26112 62.09375 99.84375 C 62.994771 99.426382 63.386118 98.338521 62.96875 97.4375 L 47.65625 64.34375 L 49.09375 64.34375 L 51.53125 64.34375 L 51.53125 57.21875 z " />
  <path
     id="reel-1"
     d="m 17.763265,10.60917 c -1.849868,0 -3.349902,1.500036 -3.349902,3.349902 0,1.849868 1.500034,3.34863 3.349902,3.34863 1.849865,0 3.348629,-1.498762 3.348629,-3.34863 0,-1.849866 -1.498764,-3.349902 -3.348629,-3.349902 z m -8.0539896,5.851215 c -1.849868,0 -3.3499023,1.500032 -3.3499023,3.349898 0,1.849866 1.5000343,3.349897 3.3499023,3.349897 1.8498656,0 3.3498996,-1.500031 3.3498996,-3.349897 0,-1.849866 -1.500034,-3.349898 -3.3498996,-3.349898 z m 16.1016246,0 c -1.849868,0 -3.3499,1.500032 -3.3499,3.349898 0,1.849866 1.500032,3.349897 3.3499,3.349897 1.849865,0 3.348629,-1.500031 3.348629,-3.349897 0,-1.849866 -1.498764,-3.349898 -3.348629,-3.349898 z m -13.023579,9.460259 c -1.849867,0 -3.3498994,1.500032 -3.3498994,3.349902 0,1.849865 1.5000324,3.348629 3.3498994,3.348629 1.849867,0 3.3499,-1.498764 3.3499,-3.348629 0,-1.84987 -1.500033,-3.349902 -3.3499,-3.349902 z m 9.950613,0 c -1.849866,0 -3.348629,1.500032 -3.348629,3.349902 0,1.849865 1.498763,3.348629 3.348629,3.348629 1.849865,0 3.349901,-1.498764 3.349901,-3.348629 0,-1.84987 -1.500036,-3.349902 -3.349901,-3.349902 z">
    <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       attributeType="XML"
       type="rotate"
       dur="2s"
       begin="0"
       from="0 17.66 22.74"
       to="360 17.66 22.74"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  <path
     id="reel-2"
     d="m 51.483904,5.8171007 c -1.849872,0 -3.349908,1.5000388 -3.349908,3.3499074 0,1.8498709 1.500036,3.3486359 3.349908,3.3486359 1.849868,0 3.348635,-1.498765 3.348635,-3.3486359 0,-1.8498686 -1.498767,-3.3499074 -3.348635,-3.3499074 z M 43.4299,11.668326 c -1.849872,0 -3.349908,1.500034 -3.349908,3.349904 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.349903 3.349908,3.349903 1.849869,0 3.349906,-1.500034 3.349906,-3.349903 0,-1.84987 -1.500037,-3.349904 -3.349906,-3.349904 z m 16.101654,0 c -1.849871,0 -3.349907,1.500034 -3.349907,3.349904 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.349903 3.349907,3.349903 1.849867,0 3.348635,-1.500034 3.348635,-3.349903 0,-1.84987 -1.498768,-3.349904 -3.348635,-3.349904 z m -13.023602,9.460276 c -1.849871,0 -3.349907,1.500034 -3.349907,3.349908 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.348635 3.349907,3.348635 1.849869,0 3.349905,-1.498766 3.349905,-3.348635 0,-1.849874 -1.500036,-3.349908 -3.349905,-3.349908 z m 9.950632,0 c -1.849872,0 -3.348637,1.500034 -3.348637,3.349908 0,1.849869 1.498765,3.348635 3.348637,3.348635 1.849867,0 3.349905,-1.498766 3.349905,-3.348635 0,-1.849874 -1.500038,-3.349908 -3.349905,-3.349908 z">
    <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       attributeType="XML"
       type="rotate"
       dur="3.6s"
       begin="0"
       from="0 51.4 17.7"
       to="360 51.4 17.7"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>

<span>Loading&hellip;</span>
</div>
```

JS with jQuery Imported:-

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
})
```

JS without jQuery:-

```
var preloader = document.getElementById("loader");
function fadeOutnojquery(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 1;
  var interpreloader = setInterval(function () {
    el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - 0.05;
    if (el.style.opacity <= 0.05) {
      clearInterval(interpreloader);
      preloader.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, 15);
}
window.onload = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    fadeOutnojquery(preloader);
  }, 2000); // Preloader ms working time
};
```

Codepen:- [Codepen](https://codepen.io/fatalcoder524/pen/PoZOGBX)

Data is preloaded here because there is only 1 line of data to load.

Comment: can you please do it with vanilla javascript  without jQuery,  (there is alot to load already)

Comment: It seems there is a specific way here [https://createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/classes/LoadQueue.html], but i cant really make it out

Comment: @MrT Can you accept the answer if it helped you? It will help me a lot